# Element type is invalid: got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Jumbotron} from 'ui-library';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Jumbotron />,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

This is index.ts

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Jumbotron extends React.Component<{},{}>{
    constructor(props:{},context: {}){
        super(props,context)
    }
    render(){
        return (<h1>Hello, World </h1>);
    }
}

export default Jumbotron
```

this is the topheader defined in another library

this is index.ts of ui-library

```
export {default as Jumbotron} from './jumbotron';
export {default as TopHeader} from './topHeader';
```

i am getting following error from react

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: try `export default class Jumbotron`

Comment: i tried that already

Comment: can you show us the index file of `ui-library`. How are you exporting things?

Comment: added the index.ts

Answer (score 0):

change your ui-library file to:

```
import Jumbotron from './jumbotron';
import TopHeader from './topHeader';

export { Jumbotron }
export { TopHeader }
```

Also it looks like you are importing ui-library as an npm package. Could you verify that the file path you are importing from is correct?

```
import {Jumbotron} from 'ui-library';
```

I would expect it to be something like:

```
import {Jumbotron} from './ui-library';
```

Comment: something is up with importing and exporting - could you please try updated answer?

Comment: changing it resulted in module not found and it is seperate npm module